# Doubt on a simple aptitude question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

A mixture is composed of $8$ parts of brandy and $3$ parts of water. After adding $28$ litres of water, if the mixture contains brandy one half as much as water, then how many litres of brandy does it contain?

To me, initial $3x$ and $8x$ 
$8x = \dfrac{3x+28}{2}$ leads to solution

But in text, this is done as $8x = \dfrac{(3x+28)3}{2}$

Is my calculation right? I guess it is a simple one. But to make sure I am right, please comment

[Text Reference : Q:33](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=S7n3cubPeGUC&pg=SL3-PA39&lpg=SL3-PA39&dq=one%20half%20as%20much%20as%20water&source=bl&ots=AEYd_RUU9c&sig=sgy5-RBBKOrtf3lQjfqKITqFE9s&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAGoVChMIo5GL2KvyxgIVwUCmCh0uEQPv#v=onepage&q=one%20half%20as%20much%20as%20water&f=false) :

Comment: What's x? $$$$$$

Comment: x is taken as a constant

Comment: That doesn't really explain anything. You need to explain what x is and how you got your equation or we can't help you.

Comment: More importantly YOU need to have a clear idea of what you're writing.

Comment: His $x$ is how much liquid per part, so his intial amount of liquid is $11x$. But ya, as avid19 says, you should know what each variable is when you assign it.

Comment: Thanks avid and mark, will take care hereafter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x$ be the amount in L of the mixture. Then the water amount is: $\dfrac{3x}{11}$ L, and the brandy abount is $\dfrac{8x}{11}$L. After pouring in $28$ L of water, the  new amount is $(x+28)$ L, and one third of this amount is brandy. So the brandy amount is: $\dfrac{x+28}{3}$ L. Since the brandy amount does not change before and after pouring of water into the mixture, it must be true that: $\dfrac{8x}{11} = \dfrac{x+28}{3} \to24x=11x+308 \to 13x= 308 \to x = \dfrac{308}{13} $ L. Thus the mount of brandy is: $\dfrac{8}{11}\cdot \dfrac{308}{13} = 17.23$ L.

Comment: But 8x/11 = (x+28)/2 means half of the total? in question, it is half of water. So 8x/11 = (3x/11 + 28)/2 ?

Comment: I've edited it already. Check it out.

Comment: thx. i was in the same page, but 3/2 factor given in text book confused me. thx for help.